# VB6 MDI child form : picturebox invokes Form_Load event

Tags: vb6, invoke, mdichild, form-load

I use several instances (myForm1, myForm2,etc...) of the same MDIChild form (frmChart) to display different MSCharts:

```
frmMain: 

Private Sub Open()

        dim myForm1 as frmChart
        myForm1.Show

        dim myForm2 as frmChart
        myForm2.Show

End sub
```

The problem happens when I try to save the MSChart of one opened instance, because I call a frmChart.SaveChart() function which resizes a picturebox and then the Form_Load() event is invoked, so a new extra frmChart is opened.

```
frmChart:

Public Sub SaveChart()
   picGrapgh.Height = chChart.Height
   picGrapgh.Width = chChart.Width
   picGraph.Autoredraw = True
   picGraph.Picture = picGraph.Image
   SavePicture picGraph.picture, FileName
End Sub
```

When I call that sub, it invokes the Form_Load() of the frmChart. This only happens when I use form instances (myForm1). Once I use any property of the PictureBox control of the frmChart it launches the Form_Load event. How could I prevent it?.

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards,
Ruben

Comment: instead of `frmChart.SaveChart()` use `myForm1.SaveChart` (or `myForm2`) to save the chart on that form.  If this is VB6, why the vb.Net tag?

Comment: Hi Plutonix, how can I use myForm1.SaveChart() function?. I get an error when I try to type it. I can only create functions inside the frmChart  form or in a module. Could you tell me how can I get functions or form events referenced to the myForm instances?. And sorry if you see any NET tag, I'm asking for VB6.

Comment: your code should be `dim myForm1 as NEW frmChart`, with myForm1 an instance of frmChart, the procedures in frmChart will be available in myForm1 and myForm2.

Comment: You're right Plutonix!! Great! I must use NEW and then I can call different SaveChart() functions such as myForm1.SaveChart. Thank you very much for your support!!

Comment: you're welcome; added it as an answer so you can click it and mark this as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

```
dim myForm1 as frmChart
```

This just declares that `myForm1` **will** be of the Type `frmChart` if/when one is created (instanced).  To create an actual instance of `frmChart`:

```
dim myForm1 as New frmChart
```

Since `myFormN` is now an instance of `frmChart`, you can call those procedures directly on/thru the instance variable:

```
myForm1.SaveChart
```